# getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW

Tags: php

I have two classes memberdao and member class .I am creating an object of memberdao class inside member class .here is my code

```
require_once('/../dao/memberdao.class.php');

class Member
{
public $objMemberDao= new MemberDao(); 

}
```

but it gives an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\lib\member.class.php on line 9. I am new in php so please help

Comment: Relevant part from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): *"This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."*.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. I got here via google search for this EXACT error. So clearly it's not "too localized".

Answer (score 22):

you cannot initialize new objects there. 
you must do it in the __construct function;

```
require_once('/../dao/memberdao.class.php');

class Member
{
  public $objMemberDao; 

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->objMemberDao= new MemberDao(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: and how i call the function inside memberdao?I am calling like this $objMemberDao->getMemberRecordCount($uuid); but it give me Notice: Undefined variable: objMemberDao in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\lib\member.class.php on line 38

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMemberRecordCount() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\lib\member.class.php on line 38 this error

Comment: @Biswajit: `$this->objMemberDao->....`. Have a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php.

Comment: how to use the object objMemberDao inside Class Member

Comment: @Mircea, and what if our class is a "static" class that is used without constructors and $objMemberDao is a static variable?

Answer (score 2):

create object of MemberDao class into the constructor of Member class

```
class Member
{
  public $objMemberDao; 

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->objMemberDao= new MemberDao(); 
  }
}
```