# Can't create a new SplDoublyLinkedList in PHPWord tool, syntax error on 'new'

Tags: php, class, phpword

[image]

I am trying to edit the PHPWord plugin to better fit my needs. By making the list of sections that the PHPWord main class holds, I can make it so I can insert sections into any order in the document instead of just a fixed list that I can't re-order.

But I am getting an error saying `syntax error, unexpected 'new'` and it is driving me crazy.

Does anybody else know more about this PHPWord tool? I'm not getting answers from their Github issue tracker/forum.

Something along the lines of they have their defined classes that the tools uses and I need to add it somehow as a resource? I can't just add it in for some reason.

Mucho gracias!

EDIT:

I tried making a new object on this line OTHER than array() or SplDoublyLinkedList() and no matter what other object I try to assign that is outside of the plugin scope I get the 'new' syntax error.

I also tried `new ArrayObject();` and I'm still getting the error.

PHPWord uses an `Autoloader`? This is their autoloader code, do I need to somehow include any extra classes I want to use in here somehow?

```
namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord;

/**
 * Autoloader
 */
class Autoloader
{
    /** @const string */
    const NAMESPACE_PREFIX = 'PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\';

    /**
     * Register
     *
     * @param bool $throw
     * @param bool $prepend
     * @return void
     */
    public static function register($throw = true, $prepend = false)
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'), $throw, $prepend);
    }

    /**
     * Autoload
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @return void
     */
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        $prefixLength = strlen(self::NAMESPACE_PREFIX);
        if (0 === strncmp(self::NAMESPACE_PREFIX, $class, $prefixLength)) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, substr($class, $prefixLength));
            $file = realpath(__DIR__ . (empty($file) ? '' : DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . $file . '.php');
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection Dynamic includes */
                require_once $file;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: We will need to see your code to be able to understand where the error is coming from

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_NEW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806981/getting-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-new)

Comment: This is the link to the source code: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord 
This is the only line I've changed to far.
Line 61 of PHPWord/PhpWord.php.
From: `private $sections = array();` 
To: `private $sections = new SplDoublyLinkedList();` and I get an error on the `'new'` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably gotten already past this problem, but just to write out the problem answer here in case someone stumbles here and tries to make sense of this case.

As @karthikr mentioned, the problem is using object initialization with new when defining class variable ([php: properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

i.e. the correct way to do the initialization is to move the new to the PhpWord class constructor:

```
private $sections = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $sections = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
    ...
}
```